# XERCES XML parser

Tags: windows, c++11, visual-studio-2015, xml-parsing, xerces-c

I am relatively new to programming and have been tasked with writing an xml parser using Xerces. My project is in c++ on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. Are there any good examples for Xerces being used on Windows? I have looked through Apache and it is horrible and has been talked down on by all my coworkers. Most of the help I've found has been for Linux command line or overly complicated examples for specific use cases. Is there anywhere to find a simple example of xerces being used to parse a simple, known xml file? Thank you for any and all help as it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The official Xerces documentation provides a lot of examples using both DOM and SAX parsing technique. You can find it here: https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/samples-3.html.

In order to build the examples and use them as direct references for your code, you have to follow the build instructions in https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/build-3.html.

For my personal requirements I created a VS 2013 solution for both Xerces library generation and samples compilation. The command to invoke for generation of the VS solution should for you be something simliar like

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:\libs    \path\to\xerces-c\source
```

where you can set the destination path of the output files via `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` , while `\path\to\xerces-c\source` should be the top level directory of the Xerces download, where the CMakeLists.txt file is located. Naturally you will need to install cmake on your Windows computer, which can be downloaded here: https://cmake.org/download/

Finally in order to start the examples, just use the generated VS solution or open a command prompt and start the desired program. For example use the "DOMPrint" application by calling `.\DOMPrint.exe xxx.xml`. The location of the binaries is in `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin`.

Please be aware that you will have to compile or provide the Xerces .dll files to be able to start any programm related with the library. It also can be built using the generated VS solution out of cmake.

Please don't hesitate to ask further questions, if the issue is still up-to-date!